# Speed Matlab Parallel Toolbox GPU?

Tags: performance, matlab, parallel-processing, gpu, toolbox

Parallel Toolbox installed can solve speed problems. Additionaly a GPU can increase speed of code too.
See:
http://de.mathworks.com/discovery/matlab-gpu.html
However I have a general question. If I have time consuming Matlab code which handles videos (without Parallel Toolbox installed), does it make a differnce if I have a CUDA-enabled NVIDIA GPU installed or not? Does the CPU do most of the job or is it a good idea to install a GPU anyway?
Thanks

Answer (score 2):

In general, the answer is no, without using the parallel computing toolbox matlab will not make use of your GPU. But there is a small exception, Matlab depends on the video codes installed on your system and if they decide to use the GPU, they will do so.

Comment: Intresting, thanks. Does this mean for example that videoReader or videoWriter will be supported by the GPU? Can I find it out somewhere?

Comment: You have to check the documentation for the codecs you are using, but it is likely that it not well documented.

Comment: Or to buy a CPU board and look what happens :-)